# SQL Server query to 'ftatten' data for reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with the following data, in the following structure. I'm trying to query the data to find the date ranges that someone (employee) worked.

```
  NAME     WORKED        DATE   
  Bob       YES         1/1/2019
  Bob       YES         1/2/2019
  Bob       YES         1/3/2019
  Bob       NO          1/4/2019
  Bob       YES         1/5/2019
  Bob       YES         1/6/2019
  Bob       NO          1/7/2019
  Jane      Yes         1/1/2019
  Jane      Yes         1/2/2019
  Jame      No          1/3/2019
```

Expected Result: (The Result I need)

```
Bob 1/1/2019 - 1/3/2019
Bob 1/5/2019 - 1/6/2019
Jane 1/1/2019 - 1/2/2019
```

What's the SQL syntax (SQL Server 2008+) of the query to return this result set?
thx in advance

Comment: This is a gaps and island qusetion, and there are 100's of examples on SO on how to do this. What questions have you looked at, and wwhat about them didn't you understand? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Also, syntax for 2008+ is quite broad. 2008(R2) is now completely unsupported and a lot of new functions were added in 2012+. You would be better telling us the version you are actually working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can identify the rows using `row_number()` and some date arithmetic.

So, assuming you have a row for every date:

```
select name, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date) as seqnum
      from t
      where worked = 'YES'
     ) t
group by name,
         dateadd(day, - seqnum, date);
```

Why does this work?  You are looking for adjacent dates.  If you subtract a sequence from the dates, then the result is constant -- when the dates are sequential.  This observation is used in the `group by` to get the groups you want.